# Pointless edits ... how to give feedback?

Tags: discussion, edits

I find myself recently rejecting a LOT of edits just because they don't improve the initial post *whatsoever*. They do no harm either, but they are just pointless. Is there some automatic feedback about rejections like this? I mean, after all, new users should learn about when to suggest an edit and when not?

Comment: Yes, there is automatic feedback.  The user gets it when his edit is rejected.  So pick "no improvement whatsoever".  Learning new users to edit is what it is all about.

Comment: yeah well, downvote me for asking an obvious question ... I tried to search for that, to no avail --- but I'd be happy with a "duplicate" mark if it is one. The only feedback I ever got for my only edit that was rejected was something like "be careful, one of your edits was rejected" ... not quite what I consider useful. @HansPassant thanks anyway for your comment, this is what I was thinking, too.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Are you sure they're pointless?  Can you provide some links to some edits you think are pointless?

Comment: Just putting it here as it is releated:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers.  I also added a comment to have the suggested editor included.

Comment: By pointless edits, are you referring to grammatical errors and spelling corrections?  Otherwise what would you describe as pointless?  I tend to find this quite important because it improves the quality by making the question more clear, understandable and structured.  Even when it's adding a comma or full stop.

Comment: I don't know how to find these again ... I gave an example in a comment to rene's answer, there was e.g. an edit that didn't do anything other than changing a string of SQL, so it had less newlines. (embedded in some other programming language) That's what I consider (for example) pointless.

Comment: @FelixPalmen They should show up in your Profile - click _Activity > All Actions > All_ on the relevant SE site.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu thanks for the hint -- can't find the one I was referring to right now, but here's [another example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9469844) of what I consider pointless. In fact, what I'm asking now here is for a way to give some feedback about such rejections ... but, being SO, it's clear my judgement has to be questioned first ;)

Comment: @Ash some that I've seen a lot of recently have been adding backticks around words in the body to format them as code. Except that half the time they're not actually code, but words the editor wants to emphasize,  commands, or program names. And even when they are code, formatting them doesn't improve the readability or understanding of the question at all.

Comment: Voting to leave open. The question is very clear to me: OP wants to give feedback to people who make pointless edits, and waste everybody's time in doing so.

Answer (score 11):

If I find serial *offenders* (or too enthusiastic editors) I normally visit the profile and pick one of the questions that got an approved edit from the user. I then leave a comment explaining why I am rejecting some of the edits. Something like this:

> please make sure you only edit posts that need editing, I rejected some of your latest suggested edits because they add useless bolding, whitespace or make edits to code. You might want to review the outcome of those reviews to improve your editing

If you have notorious bad editors you might want to check in one of the [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to verify if your assessment of the bad editing is correct. Either people in the chat room can help to counter any robo-reviewing or you might get the advice to raise a moderator flag on one of the posts of the user suggesting the doubtful edits. Make sure to link to some suggested-edits in the comment so the moderator gets a clear picture where to look for.

Comment: thanks, this is a constructive answer. I didn't try to find a pattern so far, It just occured to me that there are too many edits not improving the original post (the last one I rejected was just exchanging newlines in an SQL string for other whitespace). But maybe this is a good hint ... don't care about ppl doing a "pointless" edit just once :)

Comment: Now that I checked, this edit was finally rejected (as I expected), my concern is just: what will the person who suggested this edit receive? maybe just the same "be careful, one of your edits was rejected" stuff...

Comment: Yep, but if I'm not mistaken there are moderators flags raised for users with too much rejected edits, or in a short period

Comment: of course, what I was talking about is some direct feedback. I'm not talking about "vandals" (to make "offender" really clear), just about ppl being TOO enthusiastic about editing. I think there should be a "better" way by direct feedback ... but maybe I'm missing something that is already there?

Comment: No there is not anything more direct

Comment: Editors can be @replied to when their suggested edit was approved, but I'm not sure it's the best idea to put a comment on a post they edited, because the post author will also get this unnecessary notification. Maybe it's better to find some older low view post of that editor and post a comment there along with two or three review links.

Comment: @ArtjomB. yes, that is a down-side. However I do see a benefit as well: The original OP might wonder their self why the post was edited. If you leave a comment under the affected post that OP gets informed that useless edits don't have to be accepted. But I do think your approach is cleaner.

Comment: @rene: I often find myself simply fixing indentation, whitespaces and maybe adding some markdown. I think this actually does make the post more readable, although it's hardly a substantial edit. Should I stop?

Comment: @TobiaTesan Assuming you're fixing screwed up indenting and not just waging a holy war over where the opening brace goes; please continue.  Fixing indenting/word wrap on copy/pasted code is a major help.  If you're just making "opening brace goes on the previous line" or "opening brace goes on its own line" edits (when the original code used the opposite style from your preference) please stop.  Fighting that holy war does no one any good.

Comment: @TobiaTesan I checked your edits from the last 24 hours and your edits look fine. You seem to be fixing everything there is to fix. You edit for grammar, spelling, style, remove fluff, you don't forget the title. So all in all, you're fine, please keep it up. I saw one rejection, you might want to go over that one again but I wouldn't worry to much about your editing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some automatic feedback about rejections like this?

I have never been given **automatic** feedback about any of my rejected edits. I am not in the best place to comment on whether it is needed as I don't have sufficient privilege to approve or reject edits but I would like to add some of my thoughts that [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305974/1552737) hasn't captured.

> I mean, after all, new users should learn about when to suggest an edit and when not?

New users who want to actively contribute to SO and improve the quality of the site will *eventually* learn either by seeking out advice here on Meta or by looking back over their edit history. It seems to me from your post that you are coming across quite forceful with your attempt at feedback. This to me would be more harmful than the current system and more of a deterrent to new users.

After making some edits and becoming more involved with SO very gradually, and pleasantly, I searched on Meta for advice regarding what constitutes a correct edit and found using the [Accepted](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45756/my-accepted-edits) and [Rejected](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45755/my-rejected-edits) edit queries on SEDE very useful in this. Would I still be here if every time I made an edit that received even 1 reject vote SO pinged me to tell me I was wrong? Probably not, I'd have gotten fed up with being told I was wrong when I was only doing what I thought would better the site. By learning on my own what I was doing wrong and how to improve, it was a much gentler and easier approach. That is why **I think the current approach is better for encouraging new people to become active editors and improvers of SO.**

As for those who don't learn and who you notice a regular pattern occurring with [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305974/1552737) has suggested how this should be tackled. I think it should be pointed out that edits require a consensus of 3 votes to be approved or rejected so even though you are rejecting edits they may eventually be approved by other users who think they improve the site or are robo-reviewing. Also, how do you know that you are correct in rejecting the edits you have? Have you checked back through your review history to see how many of your rejected edits have been rejected or approved by others?

Comment: Well that's a nice insight, but still I think you're not representative... sorry bout that. Having access to the review queues (which I ignore mostly, shame on me, because I like to focus on the *on topic* stuff), it appears to me that LOTS of people suggest edits just for because they can ... I don't want to appear to them as some kind of "upper teacher" of course. I'm just asking for a way to give (gentle) feedback ...

Comment: and yes, I checked that ... there was ONE rejected edit, and all the feedback I got was something along the lines of being careful ... I GUESS some more insight might help newbies to do better edits or don't edit at all if not necessary.