# Was this rollback edit suggestion appropriate?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, specific-edit

Yesterday I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089959/get-path-to-all-users-start-menu-on-windows).  Last night the OP edited the question to include the working solution, so this morning I suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9833718) edit that rolled back the change. My comment on the suggested edit was:

> Rollback to Revision 2. If you want to post your complete solution, do it as an answer, not by editing the question.

A short time after proposing the rollback, the edit was rejected with the rejection reason:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

The question I have is: was this rollback edit suggestion appropriate?

I ask mainly because I'm approaching 2k reputation, and I want to be sure that the edits I'm making are good in general.  This rejected edit makes me question whether it was the appropriate course of action to take. The review history shows a 50/50 split between accept and the rejection reason above.

*(Note: The edit comment is mostly aimed at the OP so that when they look at the revision history of the question, they can see why I proposed the rollback, and what they can do instead.)*

*(Note 2: I've also avoided putting my personal opinion about what happened in this case, so I don't influence the discussion one way or the other.)*

Comment: That roll back was absolutely appropriate, and I've no idea why the reviewers thought otherwise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - My guess was that the reviewers saw a big block of red, and with the line through the "Solution" heading thought I was editing out code added to clarify the question. (I'm assuming a good faith mistake.)

Comment: Given that the excised section literally starts with **SOLUTION**, and that answers have *never* belonged in questions, I'd be inclined to give them less credit.

Comment: If this happens again, then don't forget to move that answer into an community wiki answer. OP could do that as well, but he might not show up again.

Comment: @Tom - In general good advice, I hadn't thought of that.  In this specific case, the OP already added an answer with his code.

Comment: Yes, I meant it more generally. I saw that OP noticed your advice and wrote an answer.

Comment: I'll just point out that your friendly advice needs to be left in a comment on the question *in addition to the edit summary*, because the OP is unlikely to ever actually see the edit summary let alone pay attention to it.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Totally agree. On this one one of the other users left a comment, so I upvoted it before making my edit suggestion. (I believe it was [MicroVirus](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2718186/microvirus), but the comment was removed once the OP added their own answer, so I'm not sure.)

Comment: Usually in cases like these I tend to be proactive and copy the answer into a community wiki, and link to it from the description of the edit removing it from the question. That way even if the OP never takes any further action, the information they posted in the question isn't lost.

Comment: Interestingly, two of the three reviewers *just* hit that same 2000-rep milestone.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Sometimes robo reviewers mess things up.  I'm not sure why three people failed to approve that, but they did.  Your edit comment was pretty clear, so I can't even complain about that like normal.  I'm honestly surprised that that much of a diff didn't force people to slow down and take their time with the review.

The allcaps, bold **SOLUTION** definitely does not belong in the question and should instead be another answer.  All in all, you did the right thing, and the reviewers botched this one.  You couldn't have done anything more than you did, so I would just write this one off as bad luck.  Keep doing what you're doing.

Comment: The only place where I part ways with this answer is that I'm honestly *not* surprised that this got botched. These reviewers are a good example of the kind who would benefit from some [gentle pointers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298174/1709587).

Comment: @MarkAmery I get what you mean.  I'm still surprised they messed up in this direction though.  In my experience, most are too lenient rather than too harsh.

Comment: The inappropriate leniency gets talked about more on Meta, but I see a lot of inappropriate rejections, too. Anything out of the ordinary - like doing a rollback in a suggested edit - is more likely than not to get slapped with a rejection even if it's useful.

Comment: These were not really "robo" reviewers: robo reviewers approve everything.

Answer (score 26):

It's a fine edit and ought to have been approved - answers do not belong in question.

I've made the edit directly.