# How can a user with 50 rep mess up an accepted answer?

Tags: support, edits

We can use [this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10129413)

It's very hard for me to understand how a user with rep < 100 can edit an answer which was already accepted. Moreover, he messed up the answer and it went through the approval process with success. Only one person from 4 noticed that the edits are deviating from the initial question.

Thank you for the "Rollback" button.

Comment: Please don't freak out if I messed up your question by changing Who to How and rating to rep. I have more than 2k rep, but you can still roll it back :)

Comment: I think all our feelings about this matter are properly summarized right here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers

Comment: Sure no problem :) I always accept when I mess something up. Thanks for your support.

Comment: World would be a better place if downvoters develop some guts to explain themselves.

Comment: BTW, you may want to let the person who suggested that edit know why you rolled it back. You can leave a comment on your answer addressing @infoclogged (using that syntax). You can't ping all users on the whole site that way, just people who commented on the post or edited it, but in this case, you *would* be notifying someone who edited it, so that's not a problem. I see no reason to doubt the good intentions of the edit suggestion so far, and explaining why you feel the edit suggestion was wrong may get that person to no longer make similar suggestions in the future.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This one probably isn't on the editor so much as it is the reviewers.

On the Stack Exchange network, anyone, even unregistered users, can suggest edits. If the editor has less than 2,000 rep, or doesn't have an account/isn't logged in, their edit will go to a special review queue before it can be applied. From there, the edit is shown to different reviewers. The reviewers have the following options:

- Approve. This casts one vote to let the edit be applied as-is
- Reject. This casts one vote to discard the edit.
- Improve. This first applies the edit, then applies a secondary edit the reviewer makes. The original edit needs no more votes. Improve gives a binding accept.
- Reject and Edit. This first discards the edit, once again with one vote, before letting the reviewer make their own edit.
- Skip. This skips the review without any actions from the reviewer being marked.

The original poster (OP) of a post has a binding Approve or Reject, so no matter what they select (other than skip) it will automatically either apply or discard the edit. This must be done before the review in the queue is finished, however. As you've discovered, if you miss the review, you can still rollback a bad edit.

In this case, it looks like perhaps the reviewers didn't realize the edit was breaking or they just weren't paying any attention. The editor may have been adding what they thought really was good, helpful information, or it may have been what worked on their machine.

I'll leave you with a quick quote from the [edit page in the help center:](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

> **Who makes sure that proposed edits are good?**
>
> Any user can propose edits, but not all edits are publicly visible immediately. If a user has less than 2,000 reputation, the suggested edit is placed in a review queue. Two (three on Stack Overflow) accept or reject votes are required to remove the suggested edit from the queue and either apply the edit to the post or discard it. Users with more than 2,000 reputation are considered trusted community members and can edit posts without going through the review process.

Comment: I guess, the reviewers were distracted by thinking about the shiny badges you’ll get for completing a certain number of reviews. That happens, when you award a price for quantity rather than quality…