# Comment @reply to user of rejected edit

Tags: support, comments

A user edited one of my posts. It was actually a good edit but was rejected by three people who didn't have experience in the tag.

I would like to ping the user who made the edit. However, am I correct in my understanding that [this is not possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284743)?

Comment: That is what it specifically says, yes.

Comment: Just make the edit yourself, and give credit to the submitter in the "edit summary" line. I've done this several times. In addition to their name, you can even link to the rejected edit directly.

Comment: I'm just glad you were there to override the review-queue drones who don't know how to use the skip button.

Comment: @canon, I don't have enough rep yet to view these queues. This (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue) guide for the triage queue seems to strongly recommend using "skip" as the default. I've always taken that to mean "if you aren't sure, tap skip". Is this different for the edit queue?

Comment: No, it is no different for the "suggested edits" queue, @dfd. That's what canon was saying: there are too many people who review *incorrectly* and do *not* use the skip button when they should.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Only editors who have succeeded in editing the post, can be contacted with an @reply. As @Gimby observes in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341365/comment-reply-to-user-of-rejected-edit/341368#comment431409_341365), this is specified in the post you link (emphasis mine):

> Any user who has edited the post (**does not include pending or rejected edit suggestions**).

The only option is to comment on one of the editor's own posts, if they have one. If they don't have any posts, and don't have posts on other SE sites.. you're out of luck.

It might make a good feature-request though. Sometimes you want to discuss things with the author of a rejected edit.

Comment: Related FR: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers