# What comment would help this edit get approved?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

In this question: [Javascript Reading only first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54263023/javascript-reading-only-first-value) the OP wrote what the expected result is in the comments.

I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21976094) to include the comment so people won't need to go over all the comments to find it.

Although my edit note says "Added expected result (as noted in the comments)" the reviewers rejected it as "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer."

They obviously didn't read the comment section... Usually I wouldn't expect a reviewer to read the comment section, but in this case I specifically referred to it.

1. Do you think the edit is useful?
2. What can I do to make the intent of the edit clearer for reviewers?
3. Assuming not all reviewers read the edit comment, is it acceptable to write the comment inside the edit itself?

Comment: "*is it acceptable to write the comment inside the edit itself?*" - no, not at all. Reviewers that don't read the edit message are bad reviewers and should be banned from reviewing.

Comment: I don't think it should be done either. That's why I didn't do it. But adding ___Edit___ __As mentioned in the comments, the expected...__ might be more effective to achieve the end goal which is to have a more complete question. So, if it is more effective, it might also be acceptable.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Editing the question to add relevant information needed to answer the question was the right move, and something OP should've done themselves. So, I'd say this was an oopsie on the reviewers' part.

Perhaps you could have made the fact that this was info given by OP obvious by including a link to the relevant comment(s) in the edit summary.

> Editing to include information provided by OP in the comments.
>   Relevant comment:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/q/54263023#comment95350416_54263023

Comment: Verbosity never hurts, but I'd say the message already is fine without the link. "*Adding expected results as given by OP in comments*"

Comment: tl;dr reviewers are idiots, get used to it :)

Comment: I honestly prefer the OP's original comment, and think speculating about how fairly meaningless tinkering with wording might've improved the edit's chances just shifts a portion of blame onto the suggester that he doesn't deserve. The link to the specific comment isn't needed here, and adds nothing; I'm pretty sure it won't even render as a clickable link in the review queue, so it doesn't even provide a more convenient way for a reviewer to get to the comment than the question title does. I don't think there's much more to be said about this case than what @LightnessRacesinOrbit has said.

Comment: @MarkAmery I did say it "was an oopsie on the reviewers' part". You can't help stupidity but you can always guard yourself against it. Perhaps you have heard of the term "defensive driving".

Comment: I don't dispute that in principle, @coldspeed, but I don't think that any of the tweaks to the edit summary that you propose here *do* in fact help defend against the stupidity, even slightly.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, I was going with lack of coffee https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189562/213575

Comment: @Braiam Coffee laced with cyanide perhaps ahem

Answer (score 23):

Your edit was fine. You explicitly highlighted that you were moving information from the comments into the question. I've checked the comments, and I see that you were indeed faithfully transcribing the OP's writing. I'm not convinced that there's any way you could've highlighted this more clearly.

What's more, even if you *hadn't* made this clear in your edit summary, the rejection reason chosen by the reviewers would've made no sense. I can see how a reviewer who missed that detail might've wrongly thought the edit deviated from the original author's intent, but it's *plainly* not an attempt to address the author. That rejection reason is meant to be for people who try to edit stuff like "Good question, did you ever solve this?" or "But what output are you expecting?" or "Try this! `foo(bar)`" directly into the question, not for elaborations on the question that the reviewer thinks are misguided.

I'm gonna raise a flag suggesting that both reviewers get a message pointing to this question. The quality of suggested edit reviewing is in general so bad that trying to improve it feels hopeless, especially since those of us who care [don't have the main tool that we need to do anything about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298174/1709587), but I guess that, in the absence of any non-aggressive remedy, I can at least unleash the <s>attack dogs</s> moderators and hope that something useful comes out of it.

Comment: Oh man, that feature request is truly a thing of beauty...