# Add a "Flag Reviewer" button within the review queues

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, flags

##### The Problem

Consider the following reviews:

- [Approval of plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26642009) ([source](https://github.com/Zverik/GeoSpark))
- [Approval of plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29450691) ([source](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-itac/top.html))
- [Approval of plagiarism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29450503) ([source](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/get-started-with-fortran-compiler/top.html))
- [Approval of answer being replaced with another](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29472599)
- [Approval of blatantly bad edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28925477)
- [Approval of vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25224569)
- [Approval of vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25087658)
- ... (I could list more (especially cases of approved plagiarism) simply by going through my flagging history)

All of these edits are obviously bad. There is no valid reason for any of these to have received any approvals *at all*.

This (blatantly incorrect review actions) is a very common problem in the suggested edit queue where I'm most active, although I'm sure it's a big problem in other queues as well.

##### Current Workflow

Right now, the only way to act on these is to navigate to a user's account via the link in the review results (in cases where the edit wasn't totally appalling checking a few of their previous reviews along the way to see if it's a one-off), navigate to one of their posts, and flag with a custom reason including:

- A link to the review;
- The reason it was bad;
- What action you want to be taken;

Generally, for me this occurs on tag wiki edits, so I use a flag of the form:

> <editor name>'s recent <tag name> tag edit (<review link>) is plagiarised and should not have got any approve votes. Source: <link to source>

(Note that I mention the approve votes to indicate that action against the reviewers should be taken).

This is several steps and more effort than should be needed for a task that should be straightforward. The increased effort makes it feel not even worth the effort of flagging reviewers except for the most egregious of cases (like serial approval of such bad edits).

##### Request

Please add the ability to flag reviewers directly from the queues, potentially by adding a small flag button beside their feedback in the review results banner.

I don't want the [ability to comment on reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298174/let-me-comment-on-reviews-and-notify-the-reviewers) to discuss them, this is about edits for which there is nothing to discuss and where only a flag would be appropriate.

Comment: That sounds like it is scriptable for the time this takes to get properly implemented.

Comment: @rene I would happily upvote an answer that was a userscript which allowed me to do that. _But_, having them be their own type of flag (a "review flag" or something), would separate it from the existing flags that would be possible with a userscript. That separation would indicate to mods that it's a flag of a reviewer without them having to understand that it came from a userscript (and without boilerplate to explain that, when flag comment length is already sorely limited)

Comment: While userscripts are fun and all, I'd rather not have them [as answers to feature-request posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19495/348149). Yes, a great mahy FR could be accomplished via userscripts, but that's not the point, is it?

Comment: @yivi Yes, that's why while I'd appreciate it as an answer to provide a _temporary_ solution, I wouldn't accept it :p

Comment: what a colossal bad idea, bad edit happen, and if there where many edits made, you can overlook one or two bad ones, that happens to me and i think to all of us

Comment: @nbk So... you're upset because you're one of the people that I've flagged for not paying attention before?

Comment: @nbk We're going to flag bad reviewers regardless of whether an easy button for it is added or not. The point, again, is a flag, not a "suspend this user". I assume Nick still wants the flag to be a flag that goes to the mods who then decide if a suspension is appropriate - which would make it identical to a mod flag, just without extra steps.

Comment: yes i was flagged and block from my very occational edit review i oppose all bans, thaz are based on some poor choises, anf i woud ban the ban system

Comment: @nbk Simple solution to that - stop showing a pattern of awful reviews. Tanks in advancing!

Comment: As a fellow reviewer, I can only sign off under the expressed frustration of seeing blatant plagiarism and/or vandalism approved (the former being indeed all over the place in tag wiki suggested edits), this would probably need some input from mods on whether they want to see an increase in such flags and if yes, what would be the preferred format. Not a bad idea overall, IMO (we used to have "bad SO reviews room" before, though, wouldn't it just be the same but with less transparency? Maybe it needs to be revived)

Comment: @OlegValter the room was spearheaded by Samuel Liew, who is currently taking a break from the network. Probably won't be revived until Sam returns (... If he decides to, at all)

Comment: I think this idea is a solid one, but I'm not sure I trust the ability of *Generic Reviewer Joe* to flag other reviewers properly based on the single bad review they see firsthand. The review queues in their current state provide very little info about other reviewers outside of 1) their vote on the specific review and 2) their lifetime stats. The former tells me little about their overall review ability, and the latter is already used for the review ban algorithm, right?

Comment: @zcoop98 "Generic Reviewer Joe" likely won't be looking at the results of reviews, how often do you expect the standard reviewer to look at a review and say "Oh, that post/edit/etc. is awful and should 100%, no doubt about it, be closed/rejected/etc." and then goes back to make sure that indeed nobody did act in an _obviously_ incorrect way. This isn't (primarily) about stopping mistakes on subjective reviews, this is about stopping reviewers who've made _clearly_ incorrect reviews.

Comment: @Nick That's fair; especially if the proposed flag button is only available on completed reviews. I suspect you're right that most users don't go looking through completed reviews often, if at all.

Comment: @Zoe yeah, I remember :) Just a thought crossed my mind that the idea kind of reminds me of it. It may be a good way to do something about those copy-pasted wiki/excerpt edits cluttering the review queue, actually. What worries me, though, is that it will likely not be easy to get right